# Template double ended queue (deque) implementation using dynamic allocation C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, memory-management, queue, pointers

I have written my own deque class to get a better grasp of C++ pointers and memory management. The following code is part of a larger 2D isometric game I am developing. It compiles and runs fine using MSVS express 15.

I have provided a unit test source + output. I am fairly sure there are no memory leak issues (using the global new and delete as well as placement new).

My question: Is there a computationally faster way to perform the deque copy constructor? I would also appreciate any feedback on my coding style.

```
#ifndef EVIL_DEQUE_H
#define EVIL_DEQUE_H

#include <new.h>

template<class type>
class eDeque;
//*************************************************
//              eNode
// to be used with friend class eDeque<type>
//*************************************************
template<class type>
class eNode {

    friend class eDeque<type>;

public :

                    eNode()                          : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data() {};             // default constructor
    explicit        eNode(const type & data)         : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data(data) {};         // prevent implicit conversion
                    eNode(const eNode<type> & other) : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data(other.data) {};   // copy constructor
                    // DEBUG: destructor omitted because no heap allocation occurs

    eNode<type> &   operator=(const eNode<type> & other) {                                                  // copy assignment
                                                  data.~type(); 
                                                  new (&data) type(other.data); 
                                                  return *this;};   

    const type &    Data() const                { return data; };
    type &          Data()                      { return data; };
    eNode<type> *   Prev() const                { return prev; };
    eNode<type> *   Next() const                { return next; };

private:

    eNode<type> *   prev;
    eNode<type> *   next;
    type            data;
};

//*************************************************
//              eDeque
// uses heap memory to manage copies of pushed data
// user code must check if deque is empty before accessing data
// TODO: replace the global new memory allocation with
// a custom heap memory block allocator (aligned) that has a templated/settable
// granularity and overridden new operator (to reduce the allocation overhead)
// DEBUG: will crash if it fails any new allocation (eg: PushFront, PushBack, operator=, cctor)
//*************************************************
template <class type>
class eDeque {
public:

                        eDeque();                                   // default constructor
                        eDeque(const eDeque<type> & other);         // copy constructor
                       ~eDeque();                                   // destructor

    eDeque<type> &      operator=(const eDeque<type> & other);      // copy assignment

    void                PushFront(const type & data);
    void                PushBack(const type & data);
    void                PopFront();
    void                PopBack();

    eNode<type> *       Back() const;
    eNode<type> *       Front() const;
    eNode<type> *       FromFront(int index) const;
    eNode<type> *       FromBack(int index) const;

    void                Clear();
    int                 Size() const;
    bool                IsEmpty() const;

private:

    eNode<type> *       front;
    eNode<type> *       back;
    int                 nodeCount;
};

//******************
// eDeque::eDeque
// empty eDeque
//******************
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type>::eDeque() : nodeCount(0), front(nullptr), back(nullptr) {
}

//******************
// eDeque::eDeque
//******************
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type>::eDeque(const eDeque<type> & other) {
    eNode<type> * otherIterator;

    for (otherIterator = other.back; otherIterator != nullptr; otherIterator = otherIterator->next)
        PushFront(otherIterator->data);
}

//******************
// eDeque::~eDeque
//******************
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type>::~eDeque() {
    Clear();
}

//******************
// eDeque::operator=
// deep copy back to front
//******************
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type> & eDeque<type>::operator=(const eDeque<type> & other) {
    eNode<type> * thisIterator;
    eNode<type> * otherIterator;
    eNode<type> * newFront;

/*
    // QUESTION: would this be faster than what I do in this function? Or, is heap deallocation/allocation more expensive?
    Clear();
    for (otherIterator = other.back; otherIterator != nullptr; otherIterator = otherIterator->next)
        PushFront(otherIterator->data);
*/  

    // destroy and reconstruct pre-allocated memory if *this already has some
    for (thisIterator   = back,               otherIterator  = other.back; 
         thisIterator  != nullptr     &&      otherIterator != nullptr;
         thisIterator   = thisIterator->next, otherIterator  = otherIterator->next)
        (*thisIterator) = (*otherIterator);     // DEBUG: eNode copy assignemnt

    // establish a newFront if *this had more nodes than other
    newFront = nullptr;
    if (thisIterator != nullptr && otherIterator == nullptr)
        newFront = thisIterator->prev;

    // if *this had more nodes, pop all the nodes beyond other's size, down to newFront
    while (thisIterator != newFront) {
        PopFront();
        thisIterator = front;
    }

    // if *this had fewer nodes, push all the data remaining in other onto *this
    for (/*continue moving*/; otherIterator != nullptr; otherIterator = otherIterator->next)
        PushFront(otherIterator->data);

    return *this;
}

//******************
// eDeque::PushFront
// copies the data into a new node and links it to the front
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::PushFront(const type & data) {
    eNode<type> * newFront;

    newFront = new eNode<type>(data);
    if (front == nullptr) {
        front = newFront;
        back = newFront;
    } else {
        newFront->prev = front;
        front->next = newFront;
        front = newFront;
    }
    nodeCount++;
}

//******************
// eDeque::PushBack
// copies the data into a new node and links it to the back
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::PushBack(const type & data) {
    eNode<type> * newBack;

    newBack = new eNode<type>(data);
    if (back == nullptr) {
        back = newBack;
        front = newBack;
    } else {
        newBack->next = back;
        back->prev = newBack;
        back = newBack;
    }
    nodeCount++;
}

//******************
// eDeque::PopFront
// unlinks and deletes the front node
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::PopFront() {
    eNode<type> * newFront;
    eNode<type> * oldFront;

    if (front->prev == nullptr) {           // last node in the deque
        delete front;
        front = nullptr;
        back = nullptr;
    } else {                                // more than one node in the deque
        oldFront = front;
        newFront = front->prev;
        newFront->next = nullptr;
        front = newFront;
        delete oldFront;
    }
    nodeCount--;
}

//******************
// eDeque::PopBack
// unlinks and deletes the back node
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::PopBack() {
    eNode<type> * newBack;
    eNode<type> * oldBack;

    if (back->next == nullptr) {            // last node in the deque
        delete back;
        front = nullptr;
        back = nullptr;
    } else {                                // more than one node in the deque
        oldBack = back;
        newBack = back->next;
        newBack->prev = nullptr;
        back = newBack;
        delete oldBack;
    }
    nodeCount--;
}

//******************
// eDeque::Front
//******************
template <class type>
inline eNode<type> * eDeque<type>::Front() const {
    return front;
}

//******************
// eDeque::Back
//******************
template <class type>
inline eNode<type> * eDeque<type>::Back() const {
    return back;
}

//******************
// eDeque::FromFront
// returns the node "index" nodes behind the front
// index between [ 0, Size() - 1 ]
// returns nullptr for out-of-bounds index or empty deque
//******************
template <class type>
inline eNode<type> * eDeque<type>::FromFront(int index) const {
    eNode<type> * iterator;
    int i;

    if (index >= nodeCount || index < 0)
        return nullptr;

    if (index == nodeCount - 1)
        return back;

    i = 0;
    iterator = front;
    while (i++ < index)
        iterator = iterator->prev;

    return iterator;
}

//******************
// eDeque::FromBack
// returns the node "index" nodes ahead of the back
// index between [ 0, Size() - 1 ]
// returns nullptr for out-of-bounds index or empty deque
//******************
template <class type>
inline eNode<type> * eDeque<type>::FromBack(int index) const {
    eNode<type> * iterator;
    int i;

    if (index >= nodeCount || index < 0)
        return nullptr;

    if (index == nodeCount - 1)
        return front;

    i = 0;
    iterator = back;
    while (i++ < index)
        iterator = iterator->next;

    return iterator;
}

//******************
// eDeque::Clear
// unlinks and deletes all nodes front to back
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::Clear() {
    while (!IsEmpty())
        PopFront();
}

//******************
// eDeque::Size
// current number of nodes
//******************
template <class type>
inline int eDeque<type>::Size() const {
    return nodeCount;
}

//******************
// eDeque::IsEmpty
// returns true for front == nullptr
//******************
template <class type>
inline bool eDeque<type>::IsEmpty() const {
    return front == nullptr;
}

#endif /* EVIL_DEQUE_H */
```

The following code is the unit test:

```
#include "Deque.h"

// iterate and print back to front
template<class type>
void PrintDeque(const eDeque<type> & de, const char * name) {
    eNode<int> * iterator;
    int i;

    printf("%s size == %i\n", name, de.Size());
    for (i = 0, iterator = de.Back(); iterator != nullptr; iterator = iterator->Next())
        printf("node %i == %i\n", i++, iterator->Data());
    printf("\n\n");
}

// iterate and increment by amount back to front
template<class type>
void IncrementData(const eDeque<type> & de, int amount) {
    eNode<int> * iterator;

    for (iterator = de.Back(); iterator != nullptr; iterator = iterator->Next())
        iterator->Data() += amount;
}

// unit test
int main () {
    printf("BEGIN eDeque COPY TESTS\n\n");

    eDeque<int> original;
    original.PushFront(0);
    original.PushFront(1);
    original.PushFront(2);
    original.PushFront(3);
    original.PushFront(4);
    original.PushFront(5);
    original.PushBack(6);
    original.PopBack();
    original.PopFront();
    PrintDeque(original, "original");

    eDeque<int> A(original);                    // copy constructor test
    printf("A(original)\n");
    PrintDeque(A, "A result");

    eDeque<int> B;
    printf("B.Size() < original.Size()\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B_before_copyAssign");
    B = original;                               // copy assignment test with B.Size() < original.Size()
    printf("B = original\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B result");

    eDeque<int> C;
    C.PushBack(10);
    C.PushFront(11);
    C.PushBack(12);
    C.PushFront(13);
    C.PushBack(14);
    C.PushFront(15);
    C.PushBack(16);
    C.PushFront(17);
    printf("C.Size() > original.Size()\n");
    PrintDeque(C, "C_before_copyAssign");
    C = original;                               // copy assignment test with C.Size() > original.Size()
    printf("C = original\n");
    PrintDeque(C, "C result");

    // verify the original is intact
    printf("original deque intact\n");
    PrintDeque(original, "original");

    IncrementData(C, 5);
    printf("incremented each node of C by 5\n");
    PrintDeque(C, "C result");

    printf("B.Size() == C.Size()\n");
    B = C;                                      // copy assignment test with B.Size() == C.Size()
    printf("B = C\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B result");

    printf("END eDeque COPY TESTS\n\n");
    printf("BEGIN eNODE COPY TESTS\n\n");

    eNode<int> * newData = new eNode<int>(999);
    eNode<int> * D = original.Front()->Prev();  // overwrite the node data just behind the front
    (*D) = (*newData);                          // node copy assignment test
    printf("(*D) == (*original.Font()->Prev()) = *newData\n");
    PrintDeque(original, "modified original result");

    eNode<int> E(*newData);                     // node cctor test
    delete newData;                             // E is still defined because it made a copy of the newData's data
    printf("E(*newData), delete newData, result: E.Data() == %i\n", E.Data());

    eNode<int> F(*D);                           // node cctor test (copies source node data, not source's next/prev)
    printf("F(*D) result: F.Data() == %i, F.Next() == %p, F.Prev() == %p\n", E.Data(), F.Next(), F.Prev());
    printf("END eNODE COPY TESTS\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the unit test output:

```
BEGIN eDeque COPY TESTS

original size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


A(original)
A result size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


B.Size() < original.Size()
B_before_copyAssign size == 0


B = original
B result size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


C.Size() > original.Size()
C_before_copyAssign size == 8
node 0 == 16
node 1 == 14
node 2 == 12
node 3 == 10
node 4 == 11
node 5 == 13
node 6 == 15
node 7 == 17


C = original
C result size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


original deque intact
original size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


incremented each node of C by 5
C result size == 5
node 0 == 5
node 1 == 6
node 2 == 7
node 3 == 8
node 4 == 9


B.Size() == C.Size()
B = C
B result size == 5
node 0 == 5
node 1 == 6
node 2 == 7
node 3 == 8
node 4 == 9


END eDeque COPY TESTS

BEGIN eNODE COPY TESTS

(*D) == (*original.Font()->Prev()) = *newData
modified original result size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 999
node 4 == 4


E(*newData), delete newData, result: E.Data() == 999
F(*D) result: F.Data() == 999, F.Next() == 00000000, F.Prev() == 00000000
END eNODE COPY TESTS
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You follow the rule of 3, that's good. However you still can add the move operation (move construct and move assign).

```
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type>::eDeque(eDeque<type> && other): nodeCount(0), front(nullptr), back(nullptr) {
    std::swap(nodeCount, o.nodeCount);
    std::swap(front, o.front);
    std::swap(back, o.back);
}

template <class type>
inline eDeque<type> & eDeque<type>::operator=(eDeque<type> && other) {
    Clear();
    std::swap(nodeCount, o.nodeCount);
    std::swap(front, o.front);
    std::swap(back, o.back);
}
```

You can also add emplace and move methods to add an element.

```
template <class type> inline void eDeque<type>::PushBack(type && data) {
    eNode<type> * newBack;

    newBack = new eNode<type>(std::move(data)); //requires a eNode constructor taking type&&
    if (back == nullptr) {
        back = newBack;
        front = newBack;
    } else {
        newBack->next = back;
        back->prev = newBack;
        back = newBack;
    }
    nodeCount++;
}
```

Comment: The added move semantics certainly speed up construction and assignment, but my question is directly about the copy constructor and copy assignment. I've placed a comment in the original code where my question is targeted.

Comment: Move semantics provides enough of a speed boost for my project. I'll try finding an answer about fresh heap allocation vs. placement new speeds elsewhere.