# Templated double ended queue (deque) move semantics edge cases C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, memory-management, queue, reference

My [original deque implementation and efficiency question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147302/template-double-ended-queue-deque-implementation-using-dynamic-allocation-c) lacked move semantics. After [ratchet freak](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32061/ratchet-freak) provided an example of how to define them I decided to try adding them to my deque. The unit test + output below shows that the code is working.

However, my new question is: Are there edge cases in any of my move semantic functions that I may have forgotten, and is the `data.~type();` necessary in the `eNode<type>::operator=(type && other)`? I'd also appreciate any feedback on my coding style.

```
template<class type>
class eDeque;
//*************************************************
//              eNode
// to be used with friend class eDeque<type>
//*************************************************
template<class type>
class eNode {

    friend class eDeque<type>;

public :

// ... remainder of class definition (see referenced question)

    explicit        eNode(type && data) : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) { std::swap(this->data, data); };    // move constructor
                    // DEBUG: destructor omitted because no heap allocation occurs

    eNode<type> &   operator=(eNode<type> && other) {                                                                   // move assignment
                                                  data.~type(); 
                                                  std::swap(this->data, other.data); 
                                                  return *this;};

// ... remainder of class definition (see referenced question)

private:

    eNode<type> *   prev;
    eNode<type> *   next;
    type            data;
};

template <class type>
class eDeque {
public:

// ... remainder of class definition (see referenced question)

                        eDeque(eDeque<type> && other);              // move constructor
    eDeque<type> &      operator=(eDeque<type> && other);           // move assignment
    void                PushFront(type && data);                    // emplace and move
    void                PushBack(type && data);                     // emplace and move

private:

    eNode<type> *       front;
    eNode<type> *       back;
    int                 nodeCount;
 // ... remainder of class definition (see referenced question)
};

//******************
// eDeque::eDeque
// move constructor
//******************
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type>::eDeque(eDeque<type> && other) : nodeCount(0), front(nullptr), back(nullptr) {
    std::swap(nodeCount, other.nodeCount);
    std::swap(front, other.front);
    std::swap(back, other.back);
}

//******************
// eDeque::operator=
// move assignment
//******************
template <class type>
inline eDeque<type> & eDeque<type>::operator=(eDeque<type> && other) {
    Clear();
    std::swap(nodeCount, other.nodeCount);
    std::swap(front, other.front);
    std::swap(back, other.back);
    return *this;
}

//******************
// eDeque::PushFront
// emplace and move
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::PushFront(type && data) {
    eNode<type> * newFront;

    newFront = new eNode<type>(std::move(data));
    if (front == nullptr) {
        back = newFront;
        front = newFront;
    } else {
        newFront->prev = front;
        front->next = newFront;
        front = newFront;
    }
    nodeCount++;
}

//******************
// eDeque::PushBack
// emplace and move
//******************
template <class type>
inline void eDeque<type>::PushBack(type && data) {
    eNode<type> * newBack;

    newBack = new eNode<type>(std::move(data));
    if (back == nullptr) {
        back = newBack;
        front = newBack;
    }
    else {
        newBack->next = back;
        back->prev = newBack;
        back = newBack;
    }
    nodeCount++;
}
```

The following is the parts of the unit test added to the [original source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147302/template-double-ended-queue-deque-implementation-using-dynamic-allocation-c) plus some context:

```
#include "Deque.h"

// iterate and print back to front
template<class type>
void PrintDeque(const eDeque<type> & de, const char * name) {
    eNode<int> * iterator;
    int i;

    printf("%s size == %i\n", name, de.Size());
    for (i = 0, iterator = de.Back(); iterator != nullptr; iterator = iterator->Next())
        printf("node %i == %i\n", i++, iterator->Data());
    printf("\n\n");
}

// iterate and increment by amount back to front
template<class type>
void IncrementData(const eDeque<type> & de, int amount) {
    eNode<int> * iterator;

    for (iterator = de.Back(); iterator != nullptr; iterator = iterator->Next())
        iterator->Data() += amount;
}

// unit test
int main() {
    int lValues[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    printf("BEGIN eDeque COPY TESTS\n\n");

    eDeque<int> original;
    original.PushFront(lValues[0]);
    original.PushFront(lValues[1]);
    original.PushFront(lValues[2]);
    original.PushFront(lValues[3]);
    original.PushFront(lValues[4]);
    original.PushFront(lValues[5]);
    original.PushBack(lValues[6]);
    original.PopBack();
    original.PopFront();
    PrintDeque(original, "original");


    eDeque<int> B;
    printf("B.Size() < original.Size()\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B_before_copyAssign");
    B = original;                               // copy assignment test with B.Size() < original.Size()
    printf("B = original\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B result");

    eDeque<int> C;
    // these are now emplace and move calls
    C.PushBack(10);
    C.PushFront(11);
    C.PushBack(12);
    C.PushFront(13);
    C.PushBack(14);
    C.PushFront(15);
    C.PushBack(16);
    C.PushFront(17);
    printf("C.Size() > original.Size()\n");
    PrintDeque(C, "C_before_copyAssign");
    C = original;                               // copy assignment test with C.Size() > original.Size()
    printf("C = original\n");
    PrintDeque(C, "C result");

    // verify the original is intact
    printf("original deque intact\n");
    PrintDeque(original, "original");

    IncrementData(C, 5);
    printf("incremented each node of C by 5\n");
    PrintDeque(C, "C result");

    printf("B.Size() == C.Size()\n");
    B = C;                                      // copy assignment test with B.Size() == C.Size()
    printf("B = C\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B result");

// BEGIN eDeque move semantics testing
    eDeque<int> G = eDeque<int>(B);             // copy construct an rvalue eDeque, then move construct G
    printf("eDeque<int> G = eDeque<int>(B) move construction\n");
    PrintDeque(G, "G result");

    IncrementData(B, 10);
    printf("incremented each node of B by 10\n");
    PrintDeque(B, "B result");

    G = eDeque<int>(std::move(B));              // move construct an rvalue eDeque, then move assign G (B becomes undefined/unspecified)
    printf("G = eDeque<int>(B) move assignment (B becomes unspecified)\n");
    PrintDeque(G, "G result");
    PrintDeque(B, "B result");

    int lValue = 666;
    printf("G.PushBack(std::move(lValue == 666)); G.PushFront(777) emplace and move\n");
    G.PushBack(std::move(lValue));              // emplace and move
    G.PushFront(777);                           // emplace and move
    PrintDeque(G, "G result");
// END eDeque move semantics testing

    printf("END eDeque COPY TESTS\n\n");
    printf("BEGIN eNODE COPY TESTS\n\n");

// BEGIN eNode move semantics testing
    eNode<int> H = eNode<int>(123);             // move construction
    printf("eNode<int> H = eNode<int>(123) move construction result: H.Data() == %i\n\n", H.Data());

    H = eNode<int>(456);                        // move assignment
    printf("H = eNode<int>(456) move assignment result: H.Data() == %i, H.Next() == %p, H.Prev() == %p\n\n", H.Data(), H.Next(), H.Prev());

    printf("G.PushFront(std::move(H.Data()))\n");
    G.PushFront(std::move(H.Data()));           // H.data now unspecified
    PrintDeque(G, "G result");
// END eNode move semantics testing

    printf("END eNODE COPY TESTS\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output of the relevant unit test code:

```
BEGIN eDeque COPY TESTS

original size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


B.Size() < original.Size()
B_before_copyAssign size == 0


B = original
B result size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


C.Size() > original.Size()
C_before_copyAssign size == 8
node 0 == 16
node 1 == 14
node 2 == 12
node 3 == 10
node 4 == 11
node 5 == 13
node 6 == 15
node 7 == 17  


C = original
C result size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


original deque intact
original size == 5
node 0 == 0
node 1 == 1
node 2 == 2
node 3 == 3
node 4 == 4


incremented each node of C by 5
C result size == 5
node 0 == 5
node 1 == 6
node 2 == 7
node 3 == 8
node 4 == 9


B.Size() == C.Size()
B = C
B result size == 5
node 0 == 5
node 1 == 6
node 2 == 7
node 3 == 8
node 4 == 9


eDeque<int> G = eDeque<int>(B) move construction
G result size == 5
node 0 == 5
node 1 == 6
node 2 == 7
node 3 == 8
node 4 == 9


incremented each node of B by 10
B result size == 5
node 0 == 15
node 1 == 16
node 2 == 17
node 3 == 18
node 4 == 19


G = eDeque<int>(B) move assignment (B becomes unspecified)
G result size == 5
node 0 == 15
node 1 == 16
node 2 == 17
node 3 == 18
node 4 == 19


B result size == 0


G.PushBack(std::move(lValue == 666)); G.PushFront(777) emplace and move
G result size == 7
node 0 == 666
node 1 == 15
node 2 == 16
node 3 == 17
node 4 == 18
node 5 == 19
node 6 == 777


END eDeque COPY TESTS

BEGIN eNODE COPY TESTS


eNode<int> H = eNode<int>(123) move construction result: H.Data() == 123

H = eNode<int>(456) move assignment result: H.Data() == 456, H.Next() == 0000000
0, H.Prev() == 00000000

G.PushFront(std::move(H.Data()))
G result size == 8
node 0 == 666
node 1 == 15
node 2 == 16
node 3 == 17
node 4 == 18
node 5 == 19
node 6 == 777
node 7 == 456


END eNODE COPY TESTS
```

Comment: Try your code with `eDeque<std::string>` and then with `eDeque<std::unique_ptr<int>>`.

Comment: `std::string` worked fine, but `std::unique_ptr<type>` usage exposed my lack of a `eNode ( eNode<type> && other)` move constructor. Fixed.

Comment: `eNode<std::string> H("you might need more than 24 characters here"); H = eNode<std::string>("123");` should *not* have worked, because of that explicit destructor call you were worried about. (You were right to be worried.) Where do you even use that assignment operator, though? I don't think your deque relies on that functionality (nor should it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to [Quuxplusone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16369/quuxplusone) for the test cases.

The test-case for `std::unique_ptr<type>` came up and it threw a bug-unearthing monkey-wrench in my design (as did `std::string`) during assignment operations.

I devised the following `std::unique_ptr` test to see if my explicit `data.~type();` call is necessary and I noticed that `std::unique_ptr` seems to call its pointed-to object's destructor if the `std::unique_ptr<T> & std::unique_ptr<T>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<T> && rhs)` is used, and during copy construction.

```
#include <memory>

int GUID = 0;       

typedef struct T_s {
    const char * value;
    int id;

    T_s(const char * value) : value(value), id(GUID++) {
        printf("CONSTRUCT\t(GUID %i): %s\tat address %p\n\n", id, this->value, &(this->value)); 
    };

    ~T_s() { 
        printf("DESTRUCT\t(GUID %i): %s\tat address %p\n\n", id, this->value, &(this->value)); 
    };
} T;

void DestructorTest() {

    // default construction of T, default constructon of unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<T> A(new T("ctor"));        
    printf("A->value ==\t(GUID %i): %s\tat address %p\n\n", A->id, A->value, &(A->value));

    // default construction of T, copy construction of unique_ptr
    std::unique_ptr<T> B = std::make_unique<T>(T("cctor"));     
    printf("B->value ==\t(GUID %i): %s\tat address %p\n\n", B->id, B->value, &(B->value));

    // default construction of T, move assignment of unique_ptr
    B = std::make_unique<T>(T("move")); 
    printf("B->value ==\t(GUID %i): %s\tat address %p\n\n", B->id, B->value, &(B->value));
}
```

The output of which is:

```
CONSTRUCT       (GUID 0): ctor  at address 01188AF0

A->value ==     (GUID 0): ctor  at address 01188AF0

CONSTRUCT       (GUID 1): cctor at address 00F6F6A8

DESTRUCT        (GUID 1): cctor at address 00F6F6A8

B->value ==     (GUID 1): cctor at address 01188A10

CONSTRUCT       (GUID 2): move  at address 00F6F698

DESTRUCT        (GUID 1): cctor at address 01188A10

DESTRUCT        (GUID 2): move  at address 00F6F698

B->value ==     (GUID 2): move  at address 01188A80

DESTRUCT        (GUID 2): move  at address 01188A80

DESTRUCT        (GUID 0): ctor  at address 01188AF0
```

As shown, the constructor only gets called 3 times, while the destructor gets called 5 times. This is because of temporary variables leaving scope in addition to `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor calls.

I tried the copy-and-swap idiom for my `eNode<type>` assignment operator and it seems to have resolved the `std::string` and `std::unique_ptr<int>` crashes.

Here is the rewritten `eNode<type>` assignment operator (excerpted from its class declaration):

```
eNode(eNode<type> && other)      : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data(std::move(other.data)) {};      // move constructor 
eNode(const eNode<type> & other) : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data(other.data) {};               // copy constructor

// the input copy calls the appropriate constructor first
eNode<type> &   operator=(eNode<type> other) {          
                    std::swap(data, other.data);
                    return *this;
                };
```

**SOME NOTES**

- A part of me doubts this would hold up if the template were `eDeque<eDeque<int *>>` or the like.
- I agree with @Quuxplusone that direct `eNode<type>` reassignment is not how a deque should be used, but I was curious enough about memory management and move semantics that I had to try, for science.
  I've since marked the `eNode<type>` constructors that take `eNode<type>` parameters as deleted. I believe this will aid in preventing any accidental attempts at such a thing.
- This answer will be edited if it turns out there are some strong exception safety or memory leak issues.